# Richtextbox is not populating with string value even when Messagebox has one

Tags: c#

I am implementing barcode scanning. I am using a usercontrol to view 2 different things. 1 is the GeneralController and the other is the QrTestController. Both of these are in a panel in the Form1. I am using a singleton. In my form I have created some properties and one of which is

```
private QrTestController qrTestControl;


public QrTestController QrTestControl
{
   get { return qrTestControl; }
   set { qrTestControl = value; }
}
```

then to load the GeneralController, I use this:

```
private void loadGeneralController()
{
    _instance = this;
    var gc = new GeneralController();
    gc.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    pnlMain.Controls.Add(gc);
}
```

In my GeneralController, when you click on a button, the QRTestController user control gets called like so:

```
// formMain is Form1
private void tsQrScannerTest_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!frmMain.Instance.MainContainer.Controls.ContainsKey("QrTestController"))
    {
        frmMain.Instance.QrTestControl = new QrTestController();

        frmMain.Instance.QrTestControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frmMain.Instance.MainContainer.Controls.Add(frmMain.Instance.QrTestControl);
    }
    frmMain.Instance.MainContainer.Controls["QrTestController"].BringToFront();
    frmMain.Instance.Back.Visible = true;
}
```

On the first time the QrTestControl is ran, I get my expected results, i.e., I scan then I get the information into the Richtextbox and using the Debugger, I see that it goes through my `if(rtQrMessage.InvokeRequired)`. But when I press the Back button to get to the GeneralController like so:

```
private void lBack_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(QrTestControl != null)
    {
        pnlMain.Controls.Remove(QrTestControl);
        QrTestControl.Dispose();
        QrTestControl = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
    pnlMain.Controls["GeneralController"].BringToFront();
    lBack.Visible = false;
    lblStatus.Text = "Ready";
}
```

Then I return to the QrTestController, as soon as I scan a qr code, the `if(rtQrMessage.InvokeRequired)` is not called anymore. It goes to the else but the rtQrMessage(RichTextbox) is not populated although my Messagebox renders the message. Please see my code below for the QrTestController:

```
private void InitialSetup()
{
    qrSerialController = new SerialController(string.Format("COM{0}", ComPort), 9600, 8, System.IO.Ports.StopBits.None, System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None);
    if (!qrSerialController.isConnected)
    {
        qrSerialController.Connect();
    }
    qrSerialController.ReceivedBytes += QrSerialController_ReceivedBytes;
}



private void QrSerialController_ReceivedBytes(string str)
{
    try
    {
        if (rtQrMessage.InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                rtQrMessage.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                {
                    rtQrMessage.Text = string.Empty;
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.AppendLine(QrMessage);
                    rtQrMessage.Text = sb.ToString();
                    if(rtQrMessage.Text != string.Empty) frmMain.Instance.CbQr.Checked = true;
                });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rtQrMessage.Text = string.Empty;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(str);
            rtQrMessage.Text = sb.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(str);
            if (rtQrMessage.Text != string.Empty) frmMain.Instance.CbQr.Checked = true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        frmMain.Instance.LblStatus.Text = "An error has occured in the scanning: " + ex.Message;
    }
 }
```

I badly need your help with this. Thank you.

Comment: What is `rtQrMessage`? And how it is related to `QrTestControl`? You are removing `QrTestControl` and setting it to null in `lBack_Click`, is it required?

Comment: the rtQrMessage is the RichTextbox where the Scanned Information will be placed. This is inside the UserControl called QrTestControl. I need to remove the QrTestControl as soon as I click on the lBack Button and just create a new instance if a QrTestControl is required again.

Comment: Did you debug and check, when you scan the QR code again, the code of `tsQrScannerTest_Click` is executing and adding new QrTestController to the `frmMain` ?

Comment: Yes. When I use Debugger and see it line by line, I can actually see the rtQrMessage.Text gets populated with the information but in the UI I do not see the information.

Comment: I used the rtQrMessage.Refresh() and rtQrMessage.Invalidate() but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Is frmMain.Instance.MainContainer the same thing as pnlMain? Because you add the qr control to one and remove from the other? So I'm guessing the disposed one is still in the controls map when you click the second time and it doesn't create a new one.

Comment: Yes.  frmMain.Instance.MainContainer is the same thing as pnlMain. I actually created a new approach to this but I would like to know how this issue can be resolved. Do you have a way to do it please?